# Specified cast is not valid when trying to update an array

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

This code is supposed to update the elements in the array with the current values from the database table.

So this is my C# `Application_Start` code inside `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application["admin"] = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

        string conStr = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        string CMDDDStr = "SELECT * FROM Portfolio";
        SqlDataAdapter daa = new SqlDataAdapter(CMDDDStr, conStr);
        DataSet dss = new DataSet();
        daa.Fill(dss);
        int columns_num = dss.Tables[0].Columns.Count;
        Application["services"] = new int[columns_num - 4];
        Application["updatinAdminStr"] = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection conObj = new SqlConnection(conStr);
        string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Portfolio");
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conObj);
        conObj.Open();
        SqlDataReader datareader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (datareader.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dss.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                int[] services = (int[])Application["services"];
                services[i] = (int)datareader["service" + i];
                Application["services"] = services;
            }
        }
        conObj.Close();
    }
```

And this is the SQL of my database table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Portfolio] (
[Description] NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
[ImageData]   VARBINARY (MAX) NULL,
[delete]      NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
[id]          INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[service0]    INT             NULL,
[service1]    INT             NULL,
[service2]    INT             NULL,
[service3]    INT             NULL,
[service4]    INT             NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
);
```

When I try to run it:

> Specified cast is not valid.

this is the error message:
[image]

What did I do wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: If you have null values in the DB then you'd need to check for `DBNull`

Comment: :O I just made those DB values, so they are indeed null. I didn't think that this would hurt the process. I'll fill those with 0's and update!

Comment: @juharr is there any query/code that I can add that will fill the array with 0's if the database value is null?

Comment: Also shouldn't the loop be `for (int i = 0; i < columns_num - 4; i++)`

Comment: `services[i] = datareader["service" + i] is int x ? x : 0;`

Comment: yeah, I updated the loop right after I made this post, haha. will try the line and see what's up.

Comment: You might want to try `datareader.GetOrdinal("service" + i)` to get the ordinal position of that column and then use it with `datareader.IsDBNull(ordinal) ? 0 : datareader.GetInt32(ordinal)`

Comment: :O it doesn't give me any errors... yeah this line fixed it xD thanks!

Comment: I replaced the first line, and accidentally pressed 2 Ctrl + z's so the "bad" loop returned, then I noticed it, changed the loop again, and works... I.E. the first line did the trick...